# Getting uploaded file from SWFUpload

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, swfupload

I have a SWFUpload on my page, I click the button and the file selct window comes up, I select a file but I do not know how to get the filename that was uploaded? and I dont even know if the file is being uploaded.

Can anyone help me please?

I am using ASP.NET VS2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working on swfupload but in java. I may be able to answer your question.

So after you select a file, the flash upload will prepare your files for upload. It will send the request to the upload_url. This call to upload_url is like sending a request with a 
< input type="file" name="Filedata"/ > so you can access your file if you get the Filedata after the multipart post. In other words, its just like an html page uploading your files.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Mezzie, thank you for the help, some reason it is working now with me not even doin anything, however the upload progress bar isnt showing, but I am not going to worry about that for now.